# Index that is continually written to and queried

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene 5.2.1.

I am trying to figure out how I should be opening `IndexReader`s `IndexWriter`s and `IndexSearcher`s such that I can have my index have items continually written to it whilst queries are going on.

Currently this is my code:

```
Path indexPath = Paths.get("index");
Directory dir = NIOFSDirectory.open(indexPath);

IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer());
iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);

IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexWriter, false);
```

If I start my app and start putting documents into the index, I can query fine.

However, when I stop my app and then restart, what I am observing is that the index directory is being truncated (so anything added to the directory previously is lost)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a close() on the variable dir (NIOFSDirectory), and commit() and/or close() on the indexWriter(IndexWriter).  You might need to close these to flush the rest of the data to the file.

Two Notes found in the NIOFSDirectory class for 5.2.1.  The first note is important to the Windows O/S.

NOTE: NIOFSDirectory is not recommended on Windows because of a bug in how FileChannel.read is implemented in Sun's JRE. Inside of the implementation the position is apparently synchronized. See here for details.

NOTE: Accessing this class either directly or indirectly from a thread while it's interrupted can close the underlying file descriptor immediately if at the same time the thread is blocked on IO. The file descriptor will remain closed and subsequent access to NIOFSDirectory will throw a ClosedChannelException. If your application uses either Thread.interrupt() or Future.cancel(boolean) you should use the legacy RAFDirectory from the Lucene misc module in favor of NIOFSDirectory.

Comment: Sorry, I've assuming there was an issue with the way I was opening the index. I commit/flush when I add documents, but it just so happens that I do not call close. However, I would expect that I shouldn't have to call close because what if my JVM dies?

Comment: If the JVM dies before the flush, then the data in the buffer never gets persisted to disk.   But you mentioned that you called commit/flush explicitly.  Then I would have expected that data to have been persisted to the file/directory.

Comment: The data is there, I can see it on in the file explorer, however, when I close and reopen my app, the files in the directory are deleted.

Comment: quick question, which O/S are you running on?  There is a bug report on windows: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6265734 and the API has a note  NOTE: NIOFSDirectory is not recommended on Windows because of a bug in how FileChannel.read is implemented in Sun's JRE. Inside of the implementation the position is apparently synchronized. See here for details.

Comment: Developing on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: NOTE: NIOFSDirectory is not recommended on Windows because of a bug in how FileChannel.read is implemented in Sun's JRE. Inside of the implementation the position is apparently synchronized. See here for details.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I already noted these...I am running on linux, developing on Windows.